# calling props within state React

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm trying to create a [changeLanguage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnXcp.png) feature for my React Website. When a language ("English" or "Spanish") is selected it is passed down to all components in a props.language . When these props are received I want my components to print out text in the language indicated by the props. I have written the text in the state of the component one in Spanish and another in English. When my component renders I want it to print the right state according to what props are passed down. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You've messed up the syntax. Use this: `<h4>{ this.state[this.props.language].title }</h4>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple languages, send an object as your variable for every entity you wish to translate before hand. For example your page title may be

```
let greeting = {"English":"Hello","Spanish":"Hola"}
```

Then inside your render, you would have:

```
<div className="title">{this.state[this.props.language].greeting}</div>
```